# Best way to efficiently delete SQL rows in Android

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a database table in my app in which I would only like to store the top ten highest numeric values. The columns are id(unique), name, score.

What is the best method for this? should I manually pull all records out and delete by id? or can I use a SQL Statement?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Its depends on the records of your database table. If its in less number then using query delete the rows.

Comment: If you only want to store 10 values, use a file, you don't need a relational database for this.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares I'm not sure I agree. SQL will provide him with some ease of access that a flat file won't. And I don't think the overhead of sqlite would justify not using it. It is sq*lite*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about SQLite, but in later versions of MySql, something like this works

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE column_name NOT IN (
SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT 10);
```

Basically, select everything that isn't in the top 10 and delete it

Answer (score 3):

Then what you could do is put a [Trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) on you insert for the table. Basically the trigger would check to see if there were now more than 10 rows in the table and delete the smallest row(s). The trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER clamp_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table_name
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM table_name
  WHERE column_name NOT IN (
  SELECT column_name 
  FROM table_name 
  ORDER BY column_name DESC
  LIMIT 10);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want only 10 values to be stored in the database, I only need a top 10, and don't want the size of my app growing on the users phone too much

Comment: See my modified answer to address this concern.

Comment: are you saying when I insert into the table? Any idea how this would look? I am having a hard time following the example. Thanks though

Comment: Modified my answer to include an example.

Comment: Do I have to call the trigger? or do i simply wait for the next insert and it remembers the trigger?

Comment: Once you create the trigger, there's nothing else you have to do. It will just always automatically be "triggered" after any insert on the table.